# where can i get historical daily price data of counties (especially for turkey) CDS prices?

Tags: cds, credit

i need countries historical CDS prices (especially for Turkey) but i am failed to find. can anyone suggest me a website please?

Comment: It is harsh to mark this as a duplicate when the linked answer doesn't actually point to any CDS data, but rather just a bunch of graphs from DataGrapple.

Comment: I actually need data, not graphs. It's impossible o collect data from DataGrapple cause there are just graphs. Also AssetMacro always requires to login in but i think there is a problem on that website it just never let me to register

Comment: Totally agree, nominated for reopening.  We can close if someone actually links to CDS data on the other question